# RegEx for passing URLs and failing CIDR-mask

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have strings that can be URLs or CIDR-blocks. I want to determine whether a string is the path of a URL e.g.:

```
/9this can be/a/path123
/test
/r
```

or a CIDR-mask (`/0` to `/32`):

```
/24
/12
/32
```

I want the regex to exclude CIDR-masks from the matches.

This is what I have so far:

```
^[/?]((?!([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))(?=[\S]))[\S ]*$
```

Which works, except for the case where the URL-path starts with a number:

```
/23example
```

I'm coding in Go, if that matters.

Comment: Can you give more examples of what CIDR-masks look like?

Comment: Breakdown of your regex, given the target string `/9this can be/a/path123` . . . The assertion `(?!([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2])` will not allow digits. It boils down to `(?!\d)`, . . `[/?]` must be this `/?`, which can't match because a digit is after it, which is not allowed. Finally, the entire string is matched with the `[\S ]*` part, which is why it matches. It really can't be fixed, you have to start from scratch.

Comment: You want [`^[/?](?!(?:[0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2])$)\S.*`](https://regex101.com/r/uBeqFR/2) I think, but it won't work in Go regex as it is RE2 based and does not support lookarounds.

Comment: You may use two regexps in Go: if your string matches `^[/?]\S` and does not match `^/(?:[0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2])$`, then it is an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be adequate:

```
^[\/?].*[a-zA-Z].*$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/dw6Dtw/1

All it does is ensure that there's a letter in the path somewhere

Comment: This regex doesn't match paths with numbers outside the allowed range, e.g. ```/33``` or ```/555```. My question didn't define a CIDR-mask well enough, my fault.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you might want to have a complex expression to pass those, maybe just adding a quantifier with 2 plus alpha would pass that. Maybe, an expression similar to this would suffice:

```
(.+?[a-z]{2,}[0-9]?.+)
```

[image]

### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tHPUeu/1)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired or my assumptions were incorrect, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tHPUeu/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

Comment: This regex doesn't match paths with numbers outside the allowed range, e.g. ```/33``` or ```/555```. My question didn't define a CIDR-mask well enough, sorry. Also, it does not seem to detect paths that have two letters e.g. ```/te```